Sections of vector bundles on a product variety
I'm a beginner in algebraic geometry and I have a question about line bundles in projective varieties. If I have $X,Y$ complex projective varieties and a morphism $f:X\to Y$, I know that if $E$ is a vector bundle over $Y$ then pullback of sections $f^\ast:\Gamma(Y,E)\to\Gamma(X,f^\ast E)$ it is neither injective nor surjective in general. I think injectivity is easier (I think it is enough to assume $f$ is dominant, because then if two pullback sections are equal then are equal in an open set and by density are equal) but I don´t know equivalent conditions for surjectivity.
Now, if I have $E,F$ vector bundles on $X$,$Y$ and $\operatorname{pr_X}:X\times Y \to X,\operatorname{pr_Y}:X\times Y \to Y$ are the coordinate projections, I have read that global sections verify $\Gamma(X\times Y,\operatorname{pr_X}^\ast(E)\otimes \operatorname{pr_Y}^\ast(F))\cong\Gamma(X,E)\otimes\Gamma(Y,F)$. I know that there exists a more general statement known as Künneth formula, but I did not study sheaves and cohomology yet, so my question is if I can prove this isomorphism thinking about $E,F$ only as geometric vector bundles (in terms of transition matrices for example). I have already noted that there exists a natural map $\Gamma(X,E)\otimes\Gamma(Y,F)\to\Gamma(X\times Y,\operatorname{pr_X}^\ast(E)\otimes \operatorname{pr_Y}^\ast(F))$, but I can´t prove this is an isomorphism and I don´t know if there is posible without using more advanced tools.
